# Localizing the Reading of Emoji on IOS 10.0 or Higher

Tags: swift, localization, text-to-speech, emoji, avspeechsynthesizer

I've noticed an issue where IOS does not seem to localize the reading (by AVSpeechSynthesizer) of emojis on IOS 10.0 or higher, but it *does* seem to do it properly on IOS 9.3 or lower.

If you tell an AVSpeechSynthesizer that's set to English to speak an emoji by sending it the string, "", it will say "Grinning face with normal eyes."

When you change the voice language of the synth to anything other than English, such as French, for example, and send the same emoji, it should say "Visage souriant avec des yeux normaux," which is does on IOS 9.3 or lower, but on IOS 10.0 and higher, *it simply reads the English text ("Grinning face with normal eyes") in a French accent.*

I conjured up a "playground" below that shows how I came to this conclusion... although I hope I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

To reproduce this issue, create new project in XCode and attach a button to the speakNext() function.

Run on a simulator running IOS 9.3 or lower, then do the same on IOS 10.0 or higher.

Can YOU explain zat?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = 0

    let langArray = ["en","fr","de","ru","zh-Hans"]

    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func speakNext(_ sender: Any) {
        print("testing \(langArray[counter])")
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: langArray[counter])
        counter += 1
        if (counter > 4) { counter = 0 }
        synth.speak(utterance)
    }

}
```

Comment: If your app only supports English then it doesn't matter what language the user selects. It will be in English. This changed in newer versions of iOS. If you support English and French, then the text-to-speech should work for both English and French, not any language the user might select.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Maybe there is something to this, but I didn't say anything about the user selecting languages.  This has to do with setting the voice/language of an utterance via code, and there is no problem with the correct voice being set.  I tested what you're saying on IOS 10.2 by adding a French localization (clicking the '+' under localization in project settings), then setting the voice to French, and sending random emoji... and it still reads them in the correct voice, but reads English words (same as original question description).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Issue appears to be fixed in iOS 13.2! Yay!

UPDATE: After official release of iOS 13, the issue has been eclipsed/superceded by a worse issue ([iOS 13 Text To Speech (TTS - AVSpeechSynthesisVoice) crashes for some users after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111214/ios-13-text-to-speech-tts-avspeechsynthesisvoice-crashes-for-some-users-afte/58196040#58196040)).

// original post:

After notifying Apple via the Feedback Assistant, it appears that this was a bug introduced somehow in IOS 10 that went unnoticed for three consecutive versions of IOS.

After testing with IOS 13 beta 5 (17A5547d), the issue doesn't appear.

They claim that the issue has been explicitly fixed from this point forward.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like, for better or worse, emojis are now read according to the user's preferred language. If you run it on device and switch to, for example, French, then emoji will be read out in French, even if the voice synthesis voice is English. It's worthwhile noting that some languages do not seem to read out emoji. Surprisingly, this seems to be true for Japanese.

So can you change it?

Well, kind of, but I am not sure it's Apple-approved. You can set the "AppleLanguages" key in `UserDefaults.standard`. The first language in this array **when UIApplicationMain is called** will be the one used to read emoji. This means that if you change the value in your app, it will not take effect until the next time the app is started.

It's not really clear if this is a bug or intended behavior, it's certainly jarring to hear. It may be worth filing a Radar or Feedback or whatever they're calling them now with Apple.

Comment: Appreciate it.  I tried to file a bug report but no luck.  The experience has been like in the movie, Idiocracy where he puts his arm in the machine to get tattooed.  Also, clarify, we're talking about the way in which the speech engine is translating emojis into words, *not* whether or not the speech voice was set to the expected language... right?  Because I tested what youre saying -- set the device language to french in settings on IOS 10.2 -- and it sets the various language voices as expected but still processes emojis in english.  Did you test what you're saying and if so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understood the issue and Yep, I've tested it, on-device, iPad running 13.0 beta. Both setting in settings app and the trick with "AppleLanguages" **but** you have to quit and restart app for the changes to take effect, also, perhaps obviously, the AppleLanguages key overrides the settings app. What iOS versions are you testing? (I might have some other devices around I can test with).

Comment: I've verified the offending behavior on simulators from 10.0 to 12.2 non beta and a real device with 12.1.  And verified correct behavior on pre-10.0 simulators.  Is it possible the 13 beta is not to be trusted yet as far as this goes?

Comment: To be clear, I am not disagreeing that the synthesizer is ignoring the language of the voice. I am saying that the language (to speak an emoji description) used is based on the user's preferences. (And that you can kudge an override with the 'AppleLanguages' key.

Comment: OK, another update. It looks like the simulator behavior is different. I tested the 12.2 simulator and could not get it to read emoji in any language other than English. I even tried changing the language of my Mac (in case settings were bleeding through)... and it still read in English, even with both my Mac and Simulator switched to Spanish!

Comment: Thanks for your help clarifying everything -- I put in a feedback report with Apple.  Will post an update if they respond.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I was not able to come up with any better/sneaky way to get the result you probably need if your dealing with a multi-lingual app. For my part, I'll also put in similar feedback. I have some multi-lingual apps and, while emoji is not currently an issue, it may be in the future.