# iOS 13 TTS Crashes - Unable to find resource `lang'[kLanguage] - (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice, AVSpeechUtterance)

Tags: crash, text-to-speech, ios13, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

We are seeing a weird crash probably related to TTS (Fatal Exception: std::logic_error: Unable to find resource `lang'[kLanguage]). It happens for me with different languages, so it seems there is some change in iOS 13. Maybe the TextToSpeech ressources are not loaded in time. Anybody any idea? Does anybody else see this crash or better know how to fix this?

```
let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()

for voice in voices {
  if voice.name == storedName {
     synthVoice = voice
     break
  }
}

...

let utterance  = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
utterance.voice = self.synthVoice
self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)
Error: Fatal Exception: std::logic_error: Unable to find resource `lang'[kLanguage].

Trace:

8  libc++abi.dylib                0x19c929304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x19c928c58 __cxa_get_exception_ptr + 30
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x19c928c18 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 122
11 SiriTTS                        0x19f877894 VoiceConfig::report_error(unsigned int, VoiceConfig::IfMissing, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 960
12 SiriTTS                        0x19f877d88 VoiceConfigImpl::get_json(unsigned int, VoiceConfig::IfMissing) const + 144
13 SiriTTS                        0x19f8e1210 std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > VoiceConfig::get_param<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(unsigned int, VoiceConfig::IfMissing) const + 36
14 SiriTTS                        0x19f848490 NashvilleAdapterStream::NashvilleAdapterStream(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>) + 308
15 SiriTTS                        0x19f8c0158 std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<NashvilleAdapterStream, 1, false>::__compressed_pair_elem<nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&, 0ul, 1ul>(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t, std::__1::tuple<nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&>, std::__1::__tuple_indices<0ul, 1ul>) + 72
16 SiriTTS                        0x19f8c00d0 std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<NashvilleAdapterStream, std::__1::allocator<NashvilleAdapterStream> >::__shared_ptr_emplace<nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&>(std::__1::allocator<NashvilleAdapterStream>, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&&&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&&&) + 40
17 SiriTTS                        0x19f8c0078 std::__1::shared_ptr<NashvilleAdapterStream> std::__1::shared_ptr<NashvilleAdapterStream>::make_shared<nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&>(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&&&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&&&) + 52
18 SiriTTS                        0x19f8bffd8 std::__1::shared_ptr<Module> std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<std::__1::shared_ptr<Module> >::__call<void ModuleFactory::ModuleFactoryImpl::register_module<NashvilleAdapterStream>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::'lambda'(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>)&, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool> >(void ModuleFactory::ModuleFactoryImpl::register_module<NashvilleAdapterStream>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::'lambda'(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>)&&&, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&&&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>&&) + 48
19 SiriTTS                        0x19f8bdeb4 ModuleFactory::ModuleFactoryImpl::create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>) + 164
20 SiriTTS                        0x19f8bdda4 ModuleFactory::create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>) + 60
21 SiriTTS                        0x19f8652e4 GryphonPipelineFactory::pipeline_from_config(std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&) + 472
22 SiriTTS                        0x19f866a84
GryphonPipelineFactory::nashvilleFE_backend_pipeline(std::__1::shared_ptr<SharedObjectPool>) + 1140 23 SiriTTS 0x19f85ffb0 FeatureExtractorTarget::init_with_object_pool(std::__1::shared_ptr, bool) + 924
24 SiriTTS                        0x19f86027c
FeatureExtractorTarget::init_with_install_path(char const*) + 272
25 TTSSpeechBundle                0x110480b50 (Missing)
26 TTSSpeechBundle                0x1104919c4 (Missing)
27 TTSSpeechBundle                0x110491a6c (Missing)
28 TTSSpeechBundle                0x11048ef44 (Missing)
29 TTSSpeechBundle                0x110490514 (Missing)
30 TTSSpeechBundle                0x11048eefc (Missing)
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19c8781f0 _pthread_start + 124
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19c87baf0 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111214/ios-13-text-to-speech-tts-avspeechsynthesisvoice-crashes-for-some-users-afte/58196040#58196040

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 13 Text To Speech (TTS - AVSpeechSynthesisVoice) crashes for some users after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111214/ios-13-text-to-speech-tts-avspeechsynthesisvoice-crashes-for-some-users-afte)